# No Machine: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unable to open DISPLAY

Tags: java, binary, javafx, jvm, nomachine

How can I fix this error? I have installed https://github.com/qupath/qupath/releases/download/v0.3.2/QuPath-0.3.2-Linux.tar.xz from [QuPath](https://qupath.github.io/) official Website.

```
jalal@manu:~/QuPath/bin$ ls
total 1524
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jalal jalal     156 Jan 17 03:51 QuPath.sh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jalal jalal 1546304 Jan 17 03:51 QuPath
drwxrwxr-x 4 jalal jalal    4096 Jan 17 03:51 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 jalal jalal    4096 Jan 17 03:51 .
jalal@manu:~/QuPath/bin$ bash QuPath
QuPath: QuPath: cannot execute binary file
jalal@manu:~/QuPath/bin$ QuPath
QuPath: command not found
jalal@manu:~/QuPath/bin$ ./QuPath.sh
bash: ./QuPath.sh: Permission denied
jalal@manu:~/QuPath/bin$ chmod +x QuPath.sh
jalal@manu:~/QuPath/bin$ ./QuPath.sh
./QuPath.sh: line 5: /home/jalal/QuPath/bin/QuPath: Permission denied
jalal@manu:~/QuPath/bin$ ls
total 1524
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jalal jalal     156 Jan 17 03:51 QuPath.sh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jalal jalal 1546304 Jan 17 03:51 QuPath
drwxrwxr-x 4 jalal jalal    4096 Jan 17 03:51 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 jalal jalal    4096 Jan 17 03:51 .
jalal@manu:~/QuPath/bin$ chmod 777 QuPath
jalal@manu:~/QuPath/bin$ chmod 777 QuPath.sh
jalal@manu:~/QuPath/bin$ sudo ./QuPath.sh
[sudo] password for jalal: 
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option --illegal-access is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
Apr 14, 2022 3:44:49 PM com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl startup
WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @60975100'
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unable to open DISPLAY
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$new$6(GtkApplication.java:181)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.<init>(GtkApplication.java:179)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkPlatformFactory.createApplication(GtkPlatformFactory.java:41)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:146)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:291)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:293)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:163)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:659)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:679)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Failed to launch JVM
```

I have:

```
jalal@manu:~$ ls QuPath*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jalal jalal 200289784 Jan 17 05:38 QuPath-0.3.2-Linux.tar.xz

QuPath:
total 16
drwxrwxr-x  4 jalal jalal 4096 Jan 17 03:51 lib
drwxrwxr-x  2 jalal jalal 4096 Jan 17 03:51 bin
drwxrwxr-x  4 jalal jalal 4096 Jan 17 03:51 .
drwxr-xr-x 25 jalal jalal 4096 Apr 14 15:43 ..
```

and:

```
jalal@manu:~$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:printing-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:security-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
jalal@manu:~$ uname -a
Linux manu 5.4.0-105-generic #119~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 8 11:21:24 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

also:

```
jalal@manu:~$ javac --version
javac 11.0.14.1
jalal@manu:~$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.14.1 2022-02-08
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.14.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.14.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I am running Ubuntu Desktop using a No Machine client. My client is installed inside CentOS 7 and No Machine server is installed on Ubuntu 20.04. I am a sudoer on both machines.
[image]

Further clarification:  No Machine client GUI is on CentOS7, No Machine server is on Ubuntu 20.04. I am running the binary of QuPath from Ubuntu 20.04. When I sit in front of the Ubuntu 20.04 machine, the QuPath binary runs with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
jalal@manu:~/QuPath/bin$ chmod u+x ./QuPath
jalal@manu:~/QuPath/bin$ ./QuPath
```

Fixed the problem.

[image]

Credits to ***twainwek***